# jspdf or pdfmake not work correctly?

Tags: angular

I use angular 2, 
now i have some data in array format and i want to export them as a PDF?
problems:
1- i have some Farsi characters and jsPdf doesn't support this characters. 
2- i want to use pdfMake and i found many documents that explain how to include needed scripts, but when i use npm install to install pdfmake, after
i write pdfmake.createTalbe or other method , pdfmake not recognized , and use require("pdfmake") not worked.
please help me to resolve this problem, 
please if you can explain in more detail because i used many documents but
i use webpack.
i couldn't resolve my problem
thanks my friends.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code successfully to load jsPDF into an Angular 2+ service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare let require: any;
@Injectable()
export class PDFGeneratorService {
    private jsPDF;
    constructor () {
        require.ensure([
            'lib/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min'
        ], () => {
            this.jsPDF = require('lib/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min');
        }, 'jsPDF');
    }
    // Service methods
}
```

require.ensure creates a code split point in my webpack bundle so jPDF is loaded separately only when this service is created. You can just use require if you don't want that. PDFMake should also work the same. See this comment: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/150#issuecomment-156143062

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare let require: any;
@Injectable()
export class PDFGeneratorService {
    private pdfMake;
    constructor () {
        require.ensure([
            'pdfmake'
        ], () => {
            this.pdfMake = require('pdfmake');
        }, 'pdfMake');
    }
    // Service methods
}
```

Comment: so thanks, i used your answer but when i click on download button i get: EXCEPTION: Error in ......   caused by: fs.readFileSync is not a function.......

Comment: this is one of the methods of pdfmake fonts

Comment: Let my try today and see if I can reproduce it